# CoreData fetch all related objects

Tags: core-data

I have two related entities in core data

1. a book entity
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * author;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *reviews;
2. a review entity

   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * reviewer;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * reviewText;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) Book *book;

the last property in each is the relationship.

I have a book object
    Book *book

How do I fetch from CoreData all review object that are related to 'book'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`book.reviews` should return a set of review objects for that book.

Comment: so simple... I wrote mountains of stupid code... Thanks a lot !